# JBoss 7.1.1.Final migration guide to WildFly

Tags: maven, jboss, wildfly

RedHat is going to release the final version of WildFly application server (http://www.wildfly.org/) during the upcoming month. I would like to collect some migration guide to resolve maven dependencies and other things needed for migration from JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final to the new WildFly. If you have found necessary things to change between these two versions please give input to this question. Hopefully RedHat is also releasing their own migration guide once the final version of WildFly is out!

**Cargo container**

- Cargo container id from jboss71x -> wildfly8x
- WildFly support from 1.4.2 version forward (http://cargo.codehaus.org/Home)

**Code changes**

- SingletonService is not anymore in clustering.singleton package but instead in clustering.server package. Also there is new SingletonServiceBuilder functionality that is needed to use to create singleton services

**Dependencies**

- Group id: org.jboss.as -> org.wildfly, artifactId jboss-as-xxx -> wildfly-xxx

Comment: Any more information on this? I have e.g. encountered issues with the information in the persistence.xml since the class in Hibernate changed ...

Answer (score 3):

Let me add, all clustering changes are described here:

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ClusteringChangesInWildfly8

Ideally, the migration guide will be updated soon too:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/How+do+I+migrate+my+application+from+AS5+or+AS6+to+WildFly